# Azure DevOps Pipeline Release removes User Assigned Managed Identity in Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a "Dev" and "Test" Azure Data Factory. Both are assigned the same User Assigned Managed Identity.

In "Dev", I created a **linked service** which uses a **key vault** which then uses a **credential** that uses the user assigned managed identity.

Everytime I release the build to "Test", the user assigned managed identity in "Test" gets removed and then I receive this error in the deployment:

```
##[error]InvalidUserAssignedMiCredential: The referenced user assigned managed identity in the credential is not associated with the factory. Credential name: <credentialname>, Managed identity resource id: /subscriptions/<subscriptionname>/resourcegroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/<managedidentityname>
```

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

Manage identities are used to allow a VM running your Azure pipelines to act as the managed identity of that VM (you then give this managed identity access to the resources you want it to be able to access in the Azure Portal).

But there is a known issue with managed Identities.

**VM fails to start after being moved**

If you move a VM in a running state from a resource group or subscription, it continues to run during the move. However, after the move, if the VM is stopped and restarted, it fails to start. This issue happens because the VM doesn't update the managed identity reference and it continues to use an outdated URI.

**Workaround**

Trigger an update on the VM so it can get correct values for the managed identities for Azure resources. You can do a VM property change to update the reference to the managed identities for Azure resources identity.

Refer the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/known-issues